# typescript deconstruct an object and get subset of the object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get a subset of an object by deconstructing the object to a generic type. The function looks like this

```
function subset<T extends object, K extends object> (raw: T): K {
    const ss: K = raw as any;
    return ss;
}
```

T has properties: P1, P2 and P3
K has properties: P2 and P3

However, when I print out `ss`, I still get an object with P1, P2 and P3.

Can I get some help on it? Thank you.

Comment: Why in the world should a type cast like that remove properties from your objects?

Comment: Hi @AndreaSimoneCosta, I just want to extract a subset to be a key of a group. I may not use the deconstruct in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can write a function that given an object and a subset of its keys returns another object containing that subset as keys, with values taken from the source object:

```
function subset<T extends object, K extends keyof T> (obj: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).filter(([k,_]) => keys.includes(k as K))
    ) as Pick<T, K>
}
```

You cannot simply add a type cast expecting unwanted keys disappear, that is not how TypeScript work.

The `subset` function takes an object of generic type `T` and a generic subset of its keys, so the upper bound of `K` is `keyof T`, to then return an object of type `Pick<T, K>`. `Pick` simply extract from the type `T` the subset of keys `K`.
Then you have to do something similar in the value level, by filtering out unwanted keys.